# String.indexOf returns non-negative index when search string does not occur in string

Tags: c#, string, indexof

I'm parsing some log files to make a report but getting weird results with `String.IndexOf()` on a few lines. Using C# here. Most easy to explain with some code.

```
String line = "Jun 29 14:34:19 localhost axis2_http_server: CEF:0|AOPTIX|IRIS|4.1.0.1664.2839|AD214030000301-2610017|114|SDK_ACCESS|4|time=1340980459 comp=10 compinfo=CAPTURE from=8 result=0 user=Admin thread=1305:1962 msg=ation=0.00, faceColor=11.49 HR Face is ICAO compliant, inter-pupil distance=140.00. No match found on LEFT eye (database is empty). LEFT_uid=-1, blacklist=0 No match found on RIGHT eye (database is empty). RIGHT_uid=-1, blacklist=0 CAPTURE successfully completed - SOAP response sent. ";
int ctIndex = line.IndexOf("CaptureTime=");
return ctIndex;
```

> Expected: -1 
> Actual: 11

This only happens for 2 lines in about a gig of log files.

Actual implemented method

```
private TimeSpan parseDuration(string line)
{
    int ctIndex = line.IndexOf("CaptureTime=");
    ctIndex = ctIndex + "CaptureTime=".Length;
    int endIndex = line.IndexOf(" ", ctIndex);
    string sDuration = line.Substring(ctIndex, endIndex - ctIndex);
    long duration;
    if (!long.TryParse(sDuration, out duration))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error Parsing Duration");
        return TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
    duration *= 1000;
    TimeSpan tsDuration = new TimeSpan(duration*1000);
    return tsDuration;
}
```

Line Feeding Code

```
try{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FilePath);
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    while(line != null)
    {
         TimeSpan ts = parseDuration(line);
         line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
catch(Exception ex){}
finally{sr.close();}
```

Comment: Are you using multithreading?
Is snippet provided working wrong for you too? Show us your real code.
https://compilr.com/anri82/test/main.cs

Comment: I tried that, and it returns -1 as expected.

Comment: Single Thread Console Application

Comment: Sorry, but I see that `line` does not contain `CaptureTime=`. How are you going to get the index of the substring `CaptureTime=` when it does not exist in the string? Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY - that's exactly his problem. He's getting a value from `IndexOf()` when that substring does not exist.

Comment: Trying to trim the fat and only show what is necesarry for line reading. There are a bunch of if statements looking for particular strings in each line extracting different attributes.

Comment: With the edit, it was sufficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method doesn't check if ctIndex equals -1 after setting it to line.SubString(). You're then adding the length of "CaptureTime=" to ctIndex, then preforming a substring.

I would suspect that your code in its current state would not work properly for log messages that don't contain a CaptureTime= value for those reasons. Is that functional behaviour intended?

Comment: Doh, thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I feel dumb for missing that. I obviously need more coffee.

Answer (score 4):

You're not handling the case where `CaptureTime=` isn't found in the string right.

- You have `ctIndex` = -1, then you add 12 to it (the length of `CaptureTime=`).  That gives you 11.
- Then, you find the first space after that, which is the one between the timestamp and "localhost".  That's at position 15.
- Then, you get the substring from 11 to 15, which is "4:19".
- Finally, you try to parse that as a long, which it's clearly not.

You need to actually check whether `ctIndex == -1`, then handle that correctly.